# Generating hyperlinks with Thymeleaf, Spring Boot

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a problem with generating html links using Thymeleaf. I've used jpa and I have 2 tables ('users' and 'selectedUsers') I' ve made a html page where table 'users' is displayed as a list.

It works, but I want to add to every generated element of this list a hyperlink which will add value to 'selectedUsers' table. Controller should be right, but I don't know how to generate a link

`http://localhost:8080/selectedusers/create?name=<name of current element in 'users table'>`

If this is impossible to generate using thymeleaf maybe there is another way to insert values to selectedUsers.

Html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>All users</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <h1> List of all users: </h1>
    <ul th:each="user : ${users}">
        <div id="list">
            User data:
            <p th:text="${user.name} + ' | ' + ${user.email}"></p>
            <a href="/selectedusers/create?name=      ">Click here to add 
            this user to another table in database</a>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Part of controller:

```
@GetMapping("/find-all-users")
public String findUsers(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("users", userDao.findAll());
    return "findusers";
}

@Autowired
private SelectedUserDao selectedUserDao;

@RequestMapping("/selectedusers/create")
public String create(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
    String selectedUserId="";

    SelectedUser selectedUser= new SelectedUser(name);
    selectedUserDao.save(selectedUser);
    selectedUserId = String.valueOf(selectedUser.getId());
    return "findusers";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like described in the [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html) you can use the thymeleaf standard dialects.

```
<a th:href="@{/selectedusers/create(name=${user.name})}">Click here to add 
                this user to another table in database</a>
```

Internally this will produce a link like that:

`/selectedusers/create?name=anyName`