# How to add a hyperlink to a Spring Data object with thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring, thymeleaf

I have something like this:

```
<td th:text="${e.name}">My Event</td>
```

I need to add a hyperlink to e.name but I can't figure out how, and I think my google skills may be lacking as well since I can't find anything on how to do it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating hyperlinks with Thymeleaf, Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49173540/generating-hyperlinks-with-thymeleaf-spring-boot)

Answer (score 0):

Just as in a normal HTML document you'll need to wrap an `anchor` element around what you want to link. For instance like this

```
<a th:href="@{http://www.thymeleaf/documentation.html}"><td th:text="${e.name}">My Event</td></a>
```

Other variants can be found by reading the Thymeleaf [Standard URL Syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this:

```
<td><a href="http://your.url.here" th:text="${e.name}">My Event</a></td>
```

You can use `th:` attributes on any html tag.

Comment: thanks, I'd tried different ways of formatting it but none worked, guess I just missed the correct way :D

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example declaring everything in the `href` and using an expression to modify the wrapped text:

```
<td><a th:href="@{${obj.website}}" th:text="${#strings.abbreviate(obj.website,50)}" /></td>
```

One declares the `text` *and* the `href` inside of the anchor tag.